# Why Serilog isn't working even i have done configurations

Tags: c#, serilog

I have configured this in my `program.cs` and installed all packages but it isn't working.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
.Build();
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
.WriteTo
.Map("0", "Other-Other", (name, wt) => wt.File($"C:\\Serilog\\{name.Split('-')[0]}\\{name.Split('-')[1]}.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
.CreateLogger();
```

Log lines I used -

```
 logger.LogInformation("\n Start InsertPRAsync Method.");
```

Comment: You've configured it, but did you add any lines to log something?  If you did, why not show those lines as well?

Comment: Yes, I used log lines in the service method as `logger.LogInformation("\n Start InsertPRAsync Method.");`

Comment: If you use `WriteTo.File` directly (and don't use `Map`), do you get the file created/output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.UseSerilog()` to `CreateDefaultBuilder()` within the `CreateHostBuilder()` method like shown below:

Example from [Serilog.AspNetCore Documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore)

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog() // <-- Add this line
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Comment: I have used this way                                                                                                      
       `public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseLibuv()
     .UseStartup<Startup>()
     .UseSerilog();`

Comment: Try moving to before `.UseStartup<Startup>()`

Comment: I have used it in CreateHostBuilder() method as well